# How to launch an activity in lockscreen mode via adb

Tags: adb, lock-screens, shell, android-10

I have locked my android device using pattern/pin.

I want to launch activity from lockscreen itself via adb command.

Is there anyway to achieve it?

Example:
Say I have an app with activity name com.example.myactivity

When the device is not locked, I am able to launch it using:
adb shell am start -a com.sample.app/com.example.myactivity

But when I lock the device using pattern/pin from settings menu:
I am not able to launch the same app using below command:
adb shell am start -a com.sample.app/com.example.myactivity

Comment: Are you sure that the is not launched? It may be launched in background of the lock screen.

Comment: I seconded Robert's comment. I'm afraid even if it's opened in the background, the code cannot be run due to the [activity lifecycle](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Activity#activity-lifecycle).

Comment: @robert: I could see the activity when I unlock the screen after launching activity in lockscreen. But it is not getting visible in lockscreen. Is there anyway to make it visible in lockscreen in adb rooted device .

Comment: Your app needs to be  programmed in a way to allow its activity to be shown over  lock screen. See https://developer.android.com/reference/android/R.attr#showWhenLocked and https://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Activity#setShowWhenLocked(boolean)